# It can't possibly be true, but somehow maybe

Tags: grammar, modal-verbs, semantics, can-may

How is this sentence to be construed:
'**It can't possibly be true, but somehow maybe.**' ?

Can you rephrase it?

Source: https://youtu.be/X19aZ-MgibA?t=663
Would I Lie to You S17 E8. Non-UK viewers. 16 Feb 24

Comment: This is a TV celebrity game show where a person making a false statement wants to be believed and a person making a true statement wants to be disbelieved; in both cases they are asked follow-up questions on the details of their statements.  So the quote may mean something like "This person's statements are completely implausible.  Perhaps that is what they want us to think, and so they may be telling the truth."

Comment: The downtoning makes it clear that 'It can't possibly be true' was used (as it commonly is) hyperbolically. Taken literally, the sentence as a whole is nonsense, but then so are 'She's a brick', 'John's a tiger', and  'This bag weighs a ton'. //  Using more prosaic terms, 'It's extremely unlikely' is what is meant.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is it often that downtoning makes a clause construed as being used hyperbolically? Of course, "can't" contradicts "maybe".

Comment: @Henry The ending of the sentence, after some more listening to, sounds more like 'may be' rather than 'maybe'. Can it change the meaning?

Comment: @sanya6 "somehow may be [true]" would make more sense.  But since this is thinking aloud, grammar rules do not really apply.

Comment: You are misreading it: It can't possibly be true, but somehow maybe....[it is true]. Typical speech form. The three dots signal an ellipsis.

Comment: If there's a contradiction in terms if literal interpretation is demanded in examples like this, we either have a hyperbole or sloppy inaccurate language. But hyperbole exists without mitigation: "I'm so hungry I could eat a horse" / "My boss will kill me" / "I'll just be a second" / .... Context should identify this (if it doesn't, the English is poor, violating Grice's maxim of manner (clarity)).

Comment: The sentence as written looks wrong, as has been pointed out.  An editor would correct "maybe" to "may be", making it  a strange but grammatically sound sentence.  Strange because it appears to be a self contradiction.  If something may be true, then it follows that it cannot impossible for it to be true (the proposition  " 'A is true' is impossible (ie A can/may not be true" entails that the proposition "A may - ie can - be true" must be false.  Is there a version or interpretation of the statement that does not involve a self-contradiction?

Comment: "Maybe" is often used in an elliptical fashion, sometimes as a sentence on its own, indicating a possibility. There's an 80s song called Monsters and Angels with lyrics " I'm nobody's wife and I'm nobody's baby. I like it that way, but then again... maybe." And conversely a Judy Blume novel called *Then Again, Maybe I Won't*.

Comment: I'd say that "somehow maybe" is a verbless clause. It contains ellipsis of the subject pronoun "it" and the auxiliary verb "is". In full, it is "somehow maybe it is __ ", where gap = "true".

Answer (score 0):

It means that in the light of all evidence, whatever has been asserted can't be true, but one must not neglect the eventuality that something that has been overlooked makes the impossible possible.

- It can't possibly be true, but somehow there is something that defies appearances, and then it is true.

Answer (score 0):

There's ellipsis:

'It can't possibly be true, but somehow **it** may be [true].'

Comment: Yes, there's ellipsis, but of the subject pronoun "it" and the auxiliary verb "is". In full, it is "somehow maybe it is __ ", where gap is understood as "true".